# linux kernel printk output

Tags: linux, kernel, output, printk

I am new in Linux kernel development and when I try to modify a system call function by just adding a printk function in timekeep.c file,like

```
 printk("BEGIN!$$$$$\n");
```

the dmesg utility gives me output like:

```
[   75.919335] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919337] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919340] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919343] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919347] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919349] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919353] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919355] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919358] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919361] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919364] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919367] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919370] BEGIN!$$$$$
[   75.919374] BEGIN!$$$$$
```

I really don't understand how those in [] are generated. Can someone give me a hint on that?

Comment: You forgot the log level prefix: `printk(KERN_DEBUG "BEGIN!"\n");`

Answer (score 2):

Your kernel has CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME option enabled. This option is responsible for this timestamp field before `printk()` messages. From kernel config option

```
 "Selecting this option causes time stamps of the `printk()` messages to be
  added to the output of the `syslog()` system call and at the console."
```

source: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/Kconfig.debug#n2

This option is configurable at kernel configuration time, via "Kernel Hacking" configuration field. And you can enable/disable it from kernel command line parameter :`printk.time=0` (disable) or `printk.time=1` (enable).

Answer (score 0):

They're actually timestamps in seconds since the system booted.

You can safely ignore them unless you're actually *looking* for timing problems (such as a driver taking 30 seconds to do something that should be much quicker).

If you want a more readable format, you can use `dmesg -T` but you lose some precision.

```
pax> dmesg -T | tail -5l

[Mon May 27 09:08:58 2013] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[Mon May 27 09:09:00 2013] usblp0: removed
[Mon May 27 09:09:00 2013] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x3A02
[Mon May 27 09:09:09 2013] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[Mon May 27 10:09:59 2013] usblp0: removed
```

You can also remove them altogether with `dmesg -t` but then you'll lose *all* timing information.

```
pax> dmesg -t | tail -5l

ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
usblp0: removed
usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x3A02
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
usblp0: removed
```

Comment: They're actually not dmesg timestamps.  They don't come from dmesg, but the kernel itself.  They will show in kernel console messages even if you never invoke dmesg.